# Как правильно сделать наследование от шаблонного класса C++?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, наследование

У меня есть 2 класса: Матрица и Квадратная матрица. Кв. матрица - наследуется от Матрицы.
Но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы эти классы были шаблонными и тут возникла проблема - не получается нормально унаследовать шаблонный класс.

Шаблонный класс Матрица (matrix.h):

```
template <class number>
class Matrix
{

protected:
    number** M;
    int col;
    int str;

public:
    Matrix();
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix(int _str, int _col);

};
```

Шаблонный класс Квадратная матрица:

```
#include "matrix.h"
template <class number>

class SqMatrix: public Matrix<number>
{

public:
    SqMatrix() : Matrix<number>(){}
    SqMatrix(int _n);
    number Det();
};

template <class number>
SqMatrix <number> ::SqMatrix(int _n){
...
}

template <class number>
number  <number> SqMatrix::Det(){
...
}
```

Конструктор по умолчанию я беру из базового класса, а другие 2 метода - новые.

При сборке возникают ошибки (очень много одинаковых ошибок) по типу:

- `'col' was not declared in this scope;`
- `'str' was not declared in this scope;`
- `'M' was not declared in this scope;`

Т.е. не получается обратится к полям базового класса в методах класса-наследника.

Почему так происходит? Кажется, что решение очень простое, но я никак не могу понять что я делаю не так.

Comment: `this->col` или `Matrix<number>::col`.

Comment: Даже если починить ошибку, это все равно сомнительное наследование. Вы храните два числа размера в квадратной матрице, когда достаточно одного. Можно передать ссылку квадратную матрицу в функцию, которая ожидает неквадратную, и та может выставить ей неквадратный размер. И т.п.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну так на то и класс, чтобы обеспечивать инвариант `col == str` :)

Comment: или `template <class number>class SqMatrix: public Matrix<number>{public: using Matrix<number>::str;};`
`

Comment: Эти способы действительно помогли, большое спасибо!